# Async call using java 1.4

Tags: asynchronous, java1.4

i'm trying to find an easy way to execute an async call using the **1.4** java framework.

It's a very easy example... Run the async method, continue executing actions on main thread an when the async method ends raise an event to get the results.

I'll appreciate any example, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using Java 5+, you'd use the Executor framework. You're using Java 1.4, though, so you can't....

..... *but*, the Java5 executor framework is actually based upon a pre-existing concurrency library, and since then the Java5 version has been back-ported to Java 1.4 ([backport-util-concurrent](http://backport-jsr166.sourceforge.net/)).

Check out the [`java.util.concurrent` package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) in Java5 to see how this works (specifically, the `Executors` class).

Answer (score 0):

I found a really good post about how to deal with events:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2002-03/01-qa-0315-happyevent.html?page=1

Besides this and launching a thread i found the way to to what i was asking for.

Thanks!

Comment: A JavaWorld article from 9 years ago is unlikely to describe the best technique...